# How to Inject String property to javax.jms.TextMessage in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-jms

I wanted to know is there any way to add properties to JMS text Message in Spring Integration.

For example if we use normal JMS code we can always set properties to it using the below code.

```
message.setStringProperty( "AuctionType", "Reverse" );
```

**Edit**

I tried to add the header as given in Spring document but now i am getting same message Id for each message, but as i am intended to use it as ID, so i need it to be different for each message.
Below is my snapshot of Spring configuration.

```
<bean class="com.learn.util.RandomMsgId" id="randomMsgId" factory-method="getRndMsgId" scope="prototype"/>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="xmlToJMS"
    output-channel="xmltoJMSwithId">
    <int:header name="MsgId" ref="randomMsgId"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `<header-enricher/>` to add custom headers to the spring integration message and they will be mapped to JMS headers.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-header-mapping) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#header-enricher).

Comment: You are setting the header to a fixed value that's injected during initialization. Don't use a prototype bean, use `<header ... expression="@randomMsgId. getRndMsgId()" />` which will be evaluated for each message.